# Lambda Distinct not working

Tags: c#, lambda

I am unable to get a distinct list of 'Order' from my Lambda query. Even though am using the keyword `Distinct()` it is still returning repeated select list item.

```
public ActionResult Index()
{
        var query = _dbContext.Orders
                                    .ToList()
                                    .Select(x => new SelectListItem
                                    {
                                        Text = x.OrderID.ToString(),
                                        Value = x.ShipCity
                                    })
                                    .OrderBy(y => y.Value)
                                    .Distinct();

        ViewBag.DropDownValues = new SelectList(query, "Text", "Value");

        return View();
}
```

Any suggestions please?

**UPDATE**

Sorry guys I genuinely missed out the `Distinct()` from my code. I have now added it to my code.

I am basically trying to get all distinct rows where yes the values are same but the ids are different.

Same as this SQL Query......

```
SELECT distinct [ShipCity] FROM [northwind].[dbo].[Orders] ORDER by ShipCity
```

Comment: Your code has *zero* calls to `Distinct()`.

Comment: Also some general advice when using entity framework (I am assuming that _dbContext is EF context): Call to ToList() should be the last thing you do. Same goes to Single(), First(), Last(), Any(), Count() etc... You get the point... EF is "clever" enough not to make round trip to DB until it has to. SO... If you do your Where(), Select(), OrderBy() etc before you making calls that will enumerate the list, you will be a lot more efficient. I would advise you to read up a bit more about Entity Framework.

Comment: Please post the code with the Distinct call. We need to understand what you tried, or are trying to, achieve.

Comment: Hi Guys I have updated my code with the `Distinct` call. I genuinely missed it out as I had been testing it before posting the question here.

Comment: Don't call `.ToList()` First, you query should be in similar format to `db.table.Where().OrderBy().Select().Distinct().ToList()` otherwise it pulls the entire table into memory when you have .ToList()` as your first method call

Comment: @Toxicable I had formed my Lambda query in that order however it was giving me the following error `LINQ to Entities does not recognize the method 'System.String ToString()' method, and this method cannot be translated into a store expression.` So resorted to `.ToList()` as suggested on other forums? I think the error is due to me using `.ToString()` in the query?

Comment: You're correct in assuming that your use of `.ToString()` is the reason for the issue you're having is because as far as I know LINQ cannot convert a field to a string in a SQL query, you can solve this by removing the `.ToString()` and instead use whatever type it's store in the DB as

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm assuming you removed your distinct from the end of the query.

Actually for that matter i don't see how you could get duplicate orders at all since you're doing nothing in your query except selecting and your query is on a table in a database, so you already can't get the same row multiple time.

What do you call a "duplicate"? If you mean two rows with the same values except their ID that's not a duplicate at all, that's just two unrelated rows, with the same values . . .

If on the other hand you mean you expect them to be equal because you're tossing the .Distinct after the select and you're only using OrderId and ShipCity in there for which there are duplicates (and i really don't see why a column named OrderId in an orders table should have duplicates but that's another issue) then that still won't work because you're NOT selecting OrderId nor ShipCity, you're selecting a new SelectListItem and if you create two reference types with the same value, they're not equal in .NET, they need to be the same instance to be equal, not two instances with different values.

edited following your comment :

```
var query = _dbContext.Orders
                                .ToList()
                                // Group them by what you want to "distint" on
                                .GroupBy(item=>item.ShipCity)
                                // For each of those groups grab the first item, we just faked a distinct)
                                .Select(item=>item.First())
                                .Select(x => new SelectListItem
                                {
                                    Text = x.OrderID.ToString(),
                                    Value = x.ShipCity
                                })
                                .OrderBy(y => y.Value)
                                .Distinct();
```

Comment: Hi Ronan I have updated my code with `Distinct()` and I had removed it from my code as you mentioned above. Basically I am trying to get all distinct rows from the db where as you mentioned share the same value from different Id's. Something like this query `SELECT distinct [ShipCity] FROM [northwind].[dbo].[Orders] ORDER by ShipCity` Hope it makes it more clear?

Comment: @Kevin Yes but you can't do that built in with linq, there's no "DistinctBy" to allow you to make something distinct by a field instead of by the whole object (or row on DB's side). You can cheat using groupby however, editing my answer now with a sample that fits your request

Comment: Thanks @Ronan for the explanation. That resolved the issue :)